# Why is 'replacement length zero' and how can I fix it in R for my code?

Tags: r

My code is as follows for a nearest neighbour analysis for ecological patterns in R:

```
data1<-read.table("large.txt")
attach(data1)

x4<-(V1)
y4<-(V2)

r4<-numeric(133)   
nn4<-numeric(133)
d4<-numeric(133)

for(i in 1:133){
  d4<-0
  for(k in 1:133){
     d4[k]<-dist(x4[i],y4[i],x4[k],y4[k])    
     r4[i]<-min(d4[-i])    
    nn4[i]<-which(d4==min(d4[-i]))    
  }
}
```

The result which comes up is:

```
Error in nn4[i] <- which(d4 == min(d4[-i])) : replacement has length zero
```

Can anyone explain how I can fix my code/what is going wrong for 'replacement length' to be zero?
Thanks

Comment: Use `dput()` to give a sample of your dataset so we can reproduce your error. Although it's mostly likely that the contains of you which statement evaluate to `integer(0)`, which means there were no cases.

Comment: > dput()
Error in dput() : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: Is this comment of yours a joke?

Comment: @Asha: When someone suggests you use a function about which you are uninformed ... first read its help page (`?dput`) and notice in the example that it is never used without an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have this error when the function `which(d4==min(d4[-i]))`  doesn't provide a match.

Try something like this:

```
ifelse((sum(d4==min(d4[-i])==0)), NA, which(d4==min(d4[-i])))
```

Comment: is there no way to fix this? I need to find the mean from the computed answer and then plot the provided data

Comment: I have added a possible solution, for a well detailed solution provide an example of data1